# Implementing comparable java

Tags: java, compare, comparable

I am trying to sort a list of user entered tasks and dates by date using comparable interface.  I have the tasks in a external .txt file and am a little confused if I am accessing the correct variables. The program compiles, but when I try to sort the tasks, it seems to erase the contents of the file.  Here is what I have:

```
public class DueDate implements Comparable<DueDate>{

    public String addedTask = "";
    public String enteredDueDate;


    public DueDate(String addedTask, String dueDate){

        this.addedTask = addedTask;
        this.enteredDueDate = enteredDueDate;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return addedTask+"\t"+enteredDueDate+"\t";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DueDate o) {
        return this.enteredDueDate.compareTo(o.enteredDueDate);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static String fileName = "/Users/eringray/Desktop/tasklistjava/src/javatask.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int menuItem = -1;
        while(menuItem != 0){
            menuItem = menu();
            switch (menuItem){
                case 1:
                    showTaskList();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addTask();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sortList();
                case 4:
                    deleteTasks();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");

            }
        }
    }



    static int menu(){
        int choice;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n Task List Menu \n");
        System.out.println("0: Exit Menu");
        System.out.println("1: Show Tasks in List");
        System.out.println("2: Add Task to List");
        System.out.println("3: Sort Tasks by Due Date");
        System.out.println("4: Delete Tasks");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a choice: ");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            return choice;
    }

    static void showTaskList(){
        System.out.println("\nTask List\n");
        try {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line;
            int number = 1;
            while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
                line = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(number + ". " + line);
                ++number;
            }
            System.out.println();
            inFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }

    static void addTask(){
        System.out.println("\nAdd Task\n");
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
            System.out.println("Enter a Task: ");
            String addedTask = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Set Due Date for this Task(yyyy-mm-dd): ");
            String dueDate = input.nextLine();
            outFile.println(addedTask + "\t" + dueDate);
            outFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }
    static void sortList() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\nSorted List\n");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
            ArrayList<DueDate> tasks = new ArrayList<DueDate>();
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split("\t");

                if(values.length == 2) {
                    String addedTask = values[0];
                    String enteredDueDate = values[1];

                    DueDate d = new DueDate(addedTask, enteredDueDate);

                    tasks.add(d);
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(tasks);

            for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++){
                DueDate date = tasks.get(i);
                String lineText = date.toString();
                bw.write(lineText);
                bw.newLine();
            }

            br.close();
            bw.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    private static void deleteTasks(){
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert writer != null;
        writer.print("");
        writer.close();
        }

    }
```

Sorry for the extra code, but thought it might help you see what I'm trying to do.  Any suggestions would be great.  I am new to Java, so please be patient with me!  Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to sort the tasks in the file or just for outputting them sorted to the user?

Comment: Are you sure current version of the code is erasing the file? Especially can you Double check the line `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));`  in the method `sortList()` ?

Comment: I'd like to just have the tasks sorted when the user selected the Case 3.  I guess it wouldn't have to sort them in the actual file, just return them sorted

Comment: The sortList method is deleting the content in my .txt file when Case 3 is selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a missing `break` statement in your `switch` which is calling the `deleteTasks()` method after calling `sortList()`. Change your code to this and it should work fine:

```
int menuItem = -1;
while(menuItem != 0){
    menuItem = menu();
    switch (menuItem){
        case 1:
            showTaskList();
            break;
        case 2:
            addTask();
            break;
        case 3:
            sortList();
            break; //The missing break
        case 4:
            deleteTasks();
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

And the constructor of the `DueDate` class is missing the assignment of the `enteredDueDate` variable since the parameter was named `dueDate` and not `enteredDueDate`. You should change it to something like this:

```
public DueDate(String addedTask, String enteredDueDate){
    this.addedTask = addedTask;
    this.enteredDueDate = enteredDueDate;
}
```

since you are currently assigning the member variable to it's own value.
You should also consider changing the `sortList` method, especially the `BufferedWriter` or it will duplicate the list each time you call it. Something like this sould do it:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
ArrayList<DueDate> tasks = new ArrayList<DueDate>();
String line = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split("\t");
    if(values.length == 2) {
        String addedTask = values[0];
        String enteredDueDate = values[1];
        DueDate d = new DueDate(addedTask, enteredDueDate);
        tasks.add(d);
    }
}
Collections.sort(tasks);
br.close();
//Changed it to not append but overwrite the old file so it only contains the sorted list
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false));
for (DueDate date : tasks) {
    String lineText = date.toString();
    bw.write(lineText);
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```

---

**EDIT**:To print the sorted list out there are a few things you could do.
The easiest way would probably be to append a call of the `showTaskList` method to the end of the `sortList` method like this

```
    //...
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    showTaskList();
} catch (FileNotFoundE
    e.printStackTrace(
}
```

or you could loop through the `ArrayList` and print them out like this:

```
    //...
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        DueDate dueDate = tasks.get(i);
        System.out.println(i+". "+dueDate.toString());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**: The easiest way to get all `Tasks` with empty `DueDate` to the bottom when sorting is to change the `compareTo` method in `DueDate` class:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DueDate o) {
    return -this.enteredDueDate.compareTo(o.enteredDueDate);
}
```

Just negate it so all entries are sorted descending and those with empty `DueDate` will be at the end of the list (it relays on how strings are compared by default).
But if you want to use `Tasks` with no due date you'll run into a problem in your `sortList` method since the `split("\t")`method will only return an array with length 1 and your `if` condition would fail. One way to solve it looks like this:

```
//...
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split("\t");
    //To ensure it's still valid data
    if (values.length >= 1 && values.length <= 2) {
        String addedTask = values[0];
        String enteredDueDate;
        //Check whether dueDate has a value or is empty
        if (values.length == 1)
            enteredDueDate = "";
        else
            enteredDueDate = values[1];
        DueDate d = new DueDate(addedTask, enteredDueDate);
        tasks.add(d);
    }
}
//...
```

or more compact version (does exactly the same thing)

```
//...
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split("\t");
    if (values.length >= 1 && values.length <= 2)
        tasks.add(new DueDate(values[0], values.length == 1 ? "" : values[1]));
}
//...
```

Hope this helps (:

Comment: awesome, this works great!  I was just noticing the two copies of everything, thanks for the update.  One thing I'm still not getting is that when I choose Case 3, the sortlist method, it is sorting the tasks, but not showing up until I select the Case 1 again.  How would I get it so when I sortlist it would show up then

Comment: @Rassisland Edited my answer :)

Comment: @Rassisland No problem :) If it solved your problem and you are no longer looking for other answers, it would be nice if you could accept it:)

Comment: No Problem, one more question though!  Is there a fairly simple way for tasks without any due date added to go to the bottom of the task list?

Comment: @Rassisland So should they go to the bottom if you add them or if you sort them?

Comment: if you sort the tasks and a task doesn't have a due date added, it should go to the bottom of the list